Как отключить отображение ctx в SlashCommand
Я столкнулся с проблемой при написании SlashCommandGroup. Когда запускаю команду, то у меня бот требует мне ctx атрибут(скрин ниже), хотя он запрашиваться не должен ибо он используется для отправки сообщений боту.

Не знаю может быть я столкнулся с проблемой из-за использования Cog, в общем кто знает как это исправить подскажите как! Использовал библиотеку py-cord
Код:
from discord.ext import commands

whitelist = discord.SlashCommandGroup("whitelist", "whitelist xddd")

class Whitelist(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @whitelist.command(name="add", description="понг") #name="whitelist", description="понг"
    async def add(self, ctx, user: discord.Member):
        await ctx.response.send_message(f"Pong {user.name}! Latency is {self.bot.latency:.3f} ms.", ephemeral=True)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_application_command(whitelist)
    bot.add_cog(Whitelist(bot))```

